# Terminate process when compilation fails

Tags: winedt

In WinEdt when I compile a LaTeX document via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or in the TeX menu: LaTeX and an error occures, the console in the bottom window keeps running (spinning mouse).

I then terminate the process via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> or with the red cross button "terminate application". It is unperfect to having to press this button with a spinning mouse.

Is there a way to automatically terminate this console process when compilation fails?

I tried adding the macro `TerminateProcess;` somehwere in the macro `LaTeX.edt` but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all a remark: the macro `TerminateProcess` has effect only when an application has been launched through the macro `Run` or `WinExe`.

You are probably running LaTeX in the WinEdt console, so that macro has no effect at all.

Also note that when WinEdt launches an application like LaTeX and the application prompts the user for typing something, WinEdt has no control over the process, unless you manually terminate the process.

Moreover, instead of typing <kbd>Shift+Esc</kbd> you'd better to type <kbd>e</kbd> if you want to jump to the error in the document, or <kbd>x</kbd> if you simply want to terminate the process. Typing <kbd>Shift+Esc</kbd> you not only terminate the LaTeX process, but you also terminate all WinEdt macros related to the compilation process, risking to break some WinEdt functionality. When LaTeX is not responding, you can press the button "Terminate Process" and all the involved macros are terminated in a safe way.

The best way to not interact with the console is to run LaTeX in `nonstopmode`.

To do that, go to Options -> Execution Modes

[image]

and select "No Interaction" for the LaTeX application. If you want this behavior for all accessories press "Apply to All" in the "Process Flow" section.